# How to locate specific XSS hole?

Tags: php, xss

Recently i have noticed some strange stuff. In every public JavaScript file on my website there has been added redirect script at the end of every file.

I have access to access.logs and all that stuff.

How to locate trough what method did people insert this stuff?

How did they been able to access write permission on all my JavaScript files?

Comment: See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29

Comment: Post your code on pastebin or another online website.

Comment: See Here: http://www.watchguard.com/infocenter/editorial/135142.asp and here: http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Comment: @Gabriel Santos 150k lines of code

Comment: First, read my links. Second, download all your website, scan with your Antivirus to see malicious code. Third, open all folders to find malicious script, or hacker panels, etc. Finally, read logs about strange access.

Comment: You may be interested in migrating this question to the IT security stack exchange if you don't find the answers you're looking for here.

Comment: you should hire a pentester.. ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your JavaScript file has been changed, I don't think that's a XSS vulnerability.

I think they have hacked in your web server, maybe your web application has some upload vulnerability, or your web server has some 0-day vulnerabilities.

There are lots of ways to do that.

Check your web server's file system, what's the time stamp that the JavaScript files have been modified? And which user had the permission to access those files?

Comment: We have setup only specified ip logins to mysql, ssh, sftp, ftp. I think it must be then some field or GET/POST parameters. I see timestamps of change but access.log has no suspicious info on that time.

I'll try to check what users have accessed filesystem in that time.

Comment: @arma Change all your passwords.

Comment: @GabrielSantos thanks for so much info i'll try all suggestions!

Comment: @arma I don't know which system you use for the web server, maybe you'd scan for rootkits first in case there is some backdoor in your system. http://www.randombugs.com/hacker/scan-rootkits-ubuntu-debian.html

Comment: @liweijian fixed all Acunetix XSS reports and also ran rkhunter. Everything seems to be clean now and not getting hacked again so far :)